# Getting height and width of a text using Canvas

Tags: android, text, canvas

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I'm using this method to draw a text in a View:

```
    public void draw(Canvas c)
    {
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(name != null)
            c.drawText(name, getLeft(), getTop(), p);
    }
```

How can I get height and width of name text?

If I do this (p is a Paint object):

```
p.getTextBounds(name, 0, name.length(), bounds);
```

I get With `name = 'Loading', bounds = Rect(1, -10 - 42, 3);`.

I don't know why I get this strange rectangle.

Any clue?

This is my possible solution:

```
public class MyView extends ARSphericalView
{
    public String name;

    public MyView(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
        inclination = 0;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c)
    {
        /*
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        if(name != null)
            c.drawText(name, getLeft(), getTop(), p);
        */
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(name != null)
        {
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            c.drawText(name, getLeft(), getTop(), p);
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.getTextBounds(name, 0, name.length(), bounds);
            c.drawRect(bounds, p);
        }
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. I get that strange rectangle.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A text size is measured from its baseline, and has an ascent (upwards, so -y) and descent (downwards, y). The first y-value in your rect (-10) is the ascent, the second the descent (3). Width of the text is 41 (42-1). Height thus is |ascent| + |descent| is 10 + 3 = 13;

Similarly [`p.getFontMetrics()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getFontMetrics%28%29) has top and bottom attributes, which describe the highest ascent and descent the font you are using have. If you want to calculate the height of a text, then its `Math.abs(p.ascent) + Math.abs(p.descent)` You can also measure the width of a text with `p.measureText()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Paint.setTextSize()` to set the text size, and then paint it in the `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use your solution, will it fix my problem? I don't understand how it will fit my problem.

Comment: Well, if you define the size yourself, you'll know it.

Comment: I've added p.setTextSize(32);, and I'm getting the same: bounds = Rect(3, -25 - 113, 3);

Comment: textSize isn't the height of the text though?